# Verifying dd-wrt checksum (old docs out of date)

Tags: router, security, dd-wrt, hashing, md5

Trying to install dd-wrt firmware on TP Link Archer C9 v1 (AC1900) router.  Want to verify the integrity of my download, but can't find any hashes or checksums.  [Docs on the wiki about how to verify](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Checksums) are out of date/have broken links ([forum page on topic](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1052149)).  Can anyone tell me if there is an alternative way to know what my hash should be?

Answer (score 1):

When confronted with this type of problem I create an MD5 sum and SHA sums and paste each into google to see what Google comes up with - this will often give you an indication.

Its not fullproof, or guaranteed, but its the best you can get if the checksums are not published alongside the download.

Comment: Smart, thanks.  Google turns up nothing, though, even when I try versions as far back as 2015.  Guess I'll go with different custom router firmware.  I can't believe this isn't a problem for more people.